# Converting Iterated Triple Integral from Cartesian to Cylindrical Coordinates

Tags: multivariable-calculus, cylindrical-coordinates, iterated-integrals

I am trying to convert the following iterated integral from Cartesian to Cylindrical coordinates:

$$\int_{{\,0}}^{{\,\sqrt{3}}}{{\int_{{\,y}}^{{\sqrt {6 - {y^2}} }}{{\int_{{\sqrt \frac{{{x^2} + {y^2}}}{3} }}^{{\sqrt {8 - {x^2} - {y^2}} }}{{{z^3}\,dz}}\,dx}}\,dy}} $$
I tried plotting the bounds of integration, and here's how I converted them:

The boundaries projected along the $xy$-plane is the region $R$ bounded below by $x=y$ and above by $\sqrt{6-y^2}$, intersecting at $(\sqrt{3},\sqrt{3})$

Hence,

$r$ tends from $0$ to $\sqrt{3}$,
$\theta$ tends from $\frac{\pi}{4}$ to $\frac{\pi}{2}$,
$z$ from $\frac{r}{\sqrt{3}}$ to $\sqrt{8-r^2}$.

Now, the converted iterated integral is given by 
$$\int_{{\, \frac {\pi }{4}\;}}^{{\,\frac{\pi }{2}\;}}{{\int_{{\,0}}^{{\,\sqrt{3}}}{{\int_{{\,{\frac{r}{\sqrt{3}}}}}^{{\,\sqrt{8-r^2}}}{{z^3{r}\,dz}}\,dr}}\,d\theta }}$$

However, when I try to evaluate both iterated integrals into Wolfram, I don't get the same result: [Cartesian result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3sIB4.png) - [Cylindrical result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KNIfD.png)

Where could have I gone wrong with my conversion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try $0\le\theta\le\pi/4$ and $0\le r\le\sqrt6$. I have no idea where you got your "hence" limits on $r$ and $\theta$.

Comment: Thank you, they are the same when evaluated.   I got my "hence" limits by graphing $x=y$ and $x=\sqrt{6-y^2}$ onto $xy$-plane. Could you elaborate more on how you converted the bounds?

Comment: First, sketch the region, not just the bounds. $x$ starts at $x=y$ and goes to $x=\sqrt{6-y^2}$, so what portion of the circle will this be? Next, what's the radius of the circle $x^2+y^2=6$?

Comment: I understand now where I did wrong with my $r$ bounds. Now I just tried using $\pi/4\le\theta\le\pi/2$ and it shows the same result when evaluated (due to symmetry). What makes $0\le\theta\le\pi/4$ the correct bounds for this, and not $\pi/4\le\theta\le\pi/2$?

Comment: As I said, you have to sketch the region. Pick a random $y$ in the interval, say $y=1$. Where does $x$ start and where does $x$ end? You cannot skip this step. (Perhaps you're automatically letting $y$ start at $y=x$ and go up to the circle? I don't know.)

Comment: You're correct, I was automatically letting $y$ start at $y=x$ and go up the circle. I almost forgot $y$ tends from $0$ to $\sqrt{3}$, and that I should be looking at $x$ bounds which says it is from the rightmost part of the circle down to $y=x$. I fully understand now. Thank you. :)